# Integral equation to determine equilibrium

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the integral equation
$$\left(1-\frac{3x}{2}\right)f(x) + (1-x)\int_0^1 x f(x) dx + (1-x) \int_0^x f(x) dx = 0$$

with boundary conditions:
$f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ and $\int_0^1 f(x) = 1$, or with other words, $f(x)$ is a probability density function on the domain $[0,1]$.

I am wondering (1) is there a solution? (2) can we find it numerically or exactly by some procedure?

I was trying to turn this into a differential equation but I couldn't manage to do that. I also have some doubts that the system may be underspecified... ?

Background: I believe this integral equation is modelling some behavior of a system I am studying, and the integral equation would be this system in equilibrium. Successive approximations of the state of this system show that the system is converging and thus equilibrium seems likely, but I wonder if I can prove equilibrium via this way. The partial solutions of the system not in equilibrium (but almost) seem to indicate that $f(x)$ is biased to small $x$, where $f(0)$ is quite large and rapidly decreases to zero for $x > 0$, and looks similar to an exponential distribution with $\lambda \approx 8$.

Comment: Please, ignore answers by people who don't have the time to read the question. There's a serious problem with your equation: if you let $x=2/3$ (and that's well within your interval $[0,1]$), you have $$\frac13\int_0^1 x f(x) dx + \frac13 \int_0^{2/3} f(x) dx = 0,$$ and that's quite impossible, given $f(x)>0$. So I'd advise to post your derivation of that equation, to find out where the mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite

$$\frac{2-3x}{2(1-x)}f(x) + \int_0^1 x f(x) dx + \int_0^x f(x) dx = 0.$$

Then after differentiation,

$$\frac{2-3x}{2(1-x)}f'(x)+\left(1-\frac1{2(1-x)^2}\right)f(x)=0$$

which is a separable ODE.